# JavaScript force close a tab programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, screen-scraping

I'm running into a problem where some websites are failing to programmatically close:

```
window.close()
```

fails with:

```
web/Stores.war/RAPIDStorefrontAssetStore/AJAXUserInterface/javascript/FDBrowse.js:301 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at close (web/Stores.war/RAPIDStorefrontAssetStore/AJAXUserInterface/javascript/FDBrowse.js:301)
at <anonymous>:1:8
```

The offending website is: https://www.1800flowers.com/about-us-employment-opportunities?utm_medium=direct&utm_source=1800flowerscom
although this does happen to other ones too.

How can I force close? What is running in the close method which is failing? Some investigation reveals the document is failing to find some document element in a script the website is trying to run but how can I prevent it from running anything before closing? I tried to set the on_X methods to null to no success...

Comment: You can only `window.close()` a window that was opened with `window.open()`.

Comment: Yeah I am aware.

Comment: Where is your `window.close();` being executed? If you are developing a chrome extension then you can use the chrome API to close a specific tab which will should work in every case. You can also redirect to some other site or a random URL and have a script close that.

Comment: I'm working on some JS to scrape webpages, the solution of loading another website then closing does work so I might just have to use that...

Comment: `console.log(window.close)`suggests they've overridden the default `window.close()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you face is that this website has overidden the default `window.close` method with some other function.

To get around this, you should be able to call the original Window.close method from the Window object returned by `window.open()` in your master page.

```
var popup = window.open('...');
popup.close(); // should be the original Window.close method
```

But if for some reason, you absolutely want to close this method **from inside the target page**, then you can retrieve an original `Window.close` method from an iframe's `contentWindow`, and call this method on your broken page.

```js
function close(){
  console.log("It's bad to declare on the global scope");
}
console.log(window.close.toString());
window.close(); // our function

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.cssText = 'opacity:0;position:absolute';
iframe.src = 'about:blank';
iframe.onload = function() {
  console.log(iframe.contentWindow.close.toString());
  // you could call it like this
  iframe.contentWindow.close.call(window);
  // even if it will not work here because we didn't open the page programmatically
  document.body.removeChild(iframe);
};
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Here is **[a live plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fKxgXFeCCp1T5umOvRwZ?p=preview)** to better demonstrates above code.

Comment: Yeah this works, I actually have a weird chrome extension which I'm using to scrape which makes all tabs background tabs to the main process so this doesn't work but I turned off the ext and it does. Both answers helped but this might be more relevant to a wider portion of the community so I'll set this as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following statement `creates a new window` using [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), rebinds `window.close()` to the `original window`,  and subsequently `closes` both.

```
(window.close = (w => w.close() || w.close)(window.open()))()
```

---

***Explanation***

[`1800 Flowers`](https://www.1800flowers.com/about-us-employment-opportunities?utm_medium=direct&utm_source=1800flowerscom) have overriden the global [`window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) to close an `arbitrary element`.

This is evident when running `console.log(window.close)` in the browser.

```
console.log(window.close) // ƒ close(){document.getElementById("overlay").style.display="none"}
```

The `error` you cited is due to the `override` of `window.close()` and absence of `document.getElementById('overlay')`.

Hence: `"Cannot read property 'style' of null"`.

Therefore: to close `1800 Flowers` programatically, `window.close()` must be rebound (short of finding an alternative method).

Comment: How performant would this be? Couldn't I just save the close method as a different function and call that instead?

Comment: Looks like this works also. Thanks, If i set tab.close = window.close,  I can then do tab.close() successfully.